# How to bootstrap all models & services on server start express js

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, sails.js

I want to load all my models on server start up so that there will be no need to include the model file before having any interaction with the server.

Right now, i am just requiring file in all the controllers & other files, where i have a need. But i am planning to have a file & including all models & make them global on server start. So that i don't have any need to require them everywhere.

e.g :-

```
global.ConfigModel = require(APP_PATH + '/api/models/ConfigModel.js');
```

So, can you please point me out, whether it i good approach or have to use other approach.

I want to implement Sails Js framework way of bootstrapping of models & services, so that no need of requiring files again & again.

Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

Using `global` is not a good idea. But using `require()` for the desired models again and again in every service file is also cumbersome.

I would suggest you to have proper directory hierarchy and make use of `index.js`. For example,

```
project_dir/
    models/
        Book.js
        Config.js
        index.js
    services/
        auth.js
        book.js
        index.js
```

In `models/index.js`, I `require` all the models only once:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    Book: require('./Book'),
    Config: require('./Config')
};
```

Same goes for `services/index.js`.

Then anywhere, I just `require` the models directory and access each model as one of it's key.

```
'use strict';

const models = require('./models'); // It looks for index.js in ./models

function myfunc() {
    return models.Book.getAll();
}
```

This way you don't have to `require` all the models again and again, and it also looks clean.

I use it for models, helpers, services, repositories, routes.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

By passing around the express 'app' to helper methods we can collect all the models and controllers and add them to app.models and app.controllers objects respectively. We go through routes as well but don't need to store them.

The directory structure:

```
myApplication
 |__ src  
 |   |__ controllers
 |        |__ Account.js
 |            index.js
 |            User.js
 |       models
 |        |__ Account.js
 |            index.js
 |            User.js
 |       routes
 |        |__ account.js
 |            index.js
 |            user.js
 |
 |__ node_modules
 |__ package.json
 |__ 
 |__
 |__
 |
 |__ server.js
```

We use index.js files for our helper methods. These methods just loop through all js files in the directory (except for index.js) and require them.

```
// controllers/index.js
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.controllers = {};
    fs.readdirSync(__dirname).forEach(function(f) {
        if (f !== "index.js" && path.extname(f) === '.js'){
            var controller = require(path.join(__dirname,f))(app);
            app.controllers[controller.name] = controller;
        }
    });
};


// models/index.js
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.models = {};
    fs.readdirSync(__dirname).forEach(function(f) {
        if (f !== "index.js" && path.extname(f) === '.js'){
            var model = require(path.join(__dirname,f))(app);
            app.models[model.modelName] = model;
        }
    });
};


// routes/index.js
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
module.exports = function (app) {
  fs.readdirSync(__dirname).forEach(function(file) {
      if (file !== "index.js" && path.extname(file) === '.js'){
        require(path.join(__dirname, file))(app);
      }
    });
};
```

Sample model, controller and route:

```
// models/Account.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
module.exports = function(){
    var AccountSchema = new Schema({
        number : {type : String, required: true},
        owner: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
    });
    return mongoose.model("Account", AccountSchema); //'Account' is used to access this model as app.models.Account
};


// controllers/Account.js
module.exports = function(app) {
    var Account  = app.models.Account;
    var Controller = {
        name: 'Account'  //this name is used to access this controller in routes as app.controllers.Account
    };

    // POST method to create user account
    Controller.createAccount = function(req, res) {
       Account.create(req.body, function(err, result){
           if(err){
               res.status(500).send("Server Error")
           }
           else{
               res.send({message: "account created"});
           }
       })
    };

    return Controller;
};


// routes/account.js
module.exports = function (app) {
    var AccountController = app.controllers.Account;
    app.post('/api/accounts', AccountController.createAccount);
};
```

And in the server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
.
.
.
. // server configurations
.
.
.
// maintain the below order:
require("./src/models")(app); // call the method in /src/models/index.js and pass express app
require("./src/controllers")(app);
require("./src/routes")(app);
```

You would not add an empty js file in models, controllers or routes as it will through error.

Answer (score 0):

Adding variables in the global namespace can be a nightmare to maintain especially when the project gets bigger and bigger. You are polluting the global namespace without reason, other developers that possibly will join the project will not be able to understand quite easily what's going on and there is the danger to overwrite this variable. Personally, I am against this approach. It is just one line that you have to require on every file and it will keep your project safer.

If you want to get rid of the requires and to have all the dependencies present then it is better to look for dependency injection and inversion of control. There are few modules that can do this for you and I would suggest to investigate a bit about them.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But didn't u think that if i have a lot of controller files, services , i have to require file all the time. So it just a boring stuff too. That;s why i am just thinking to have a better solution for this.